# How to pass one-time argument to super class when using TypeScript (like in prototypal inheritance)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I am building small experimental javascript app for fun and have come to use the following pattern:

```
function BaseClass(some_arg){
  // do some *instance* initialization
}

function SubClass(){
  // whatever happens here
}
SubClass.prototype=new BaseClass({arg:'value'}) //the key part!
```

Part of the fun is to use and 'invent' constructs that normally I don't have with my daily language (Java).

With this pattern I have one-time initialization for *each subclass*. This looks a little like static code in standard languages (Java) but is not, because it happens in the base class once per subclass.

What is the way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: That's a bad idea; any objects created in the superconstructor will be shared by all instances of each derived class. It can lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: One base class instance per subclass is an unconventional pattern, what exactly do you need this for? There might be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe I understand very well the way to do classic OO in JS but this is not what I seek to achieve here.

@Slaks - you are right, I am aware of that
@Bergi - imagine there is some expensive initialization I want to do for each subclass but only once but the logic is shared and implemented in the parent class. imagine I have static block in each subclass that calls some `expensiveInit` method on the base class. It could be fetching some remote resources and pre-processing them to be available later when I start creating instances of the respective subclasses.

Comment: In C#, you would do that using generics and the CRTP.. I would guess that TypeScript does not have any such built-in pattern, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using default parameters in TypeScript e.g. :

```
class BaseClass{
    constructor(private arg = 'value'){ //the key part!
        // do some *instance* initialization
    }   
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  // whatever happens here
  constructor(){
      super();
  }
}
```